# How to determine the smoothness and strong convex factor of a convex function?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable. We say $f$ is $\beta$-smooth if
$$\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\| \leq \beta\|x-y\|$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

We say f is $\alpha$-strongly convex ($\alpha >0$) if for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $$f(x)-f(y) \leq \nabla f(x)^\top(x-y)-\frac{\alpha}{2}\|x-y\|^2$$

My Question: is there any general or principled way to determine the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ? Either analytic or numerical way would be appreciated!

For example (source [here](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Gradient_descent_with_constant_learning_rate_for_a_quadratic_function_of_multiple_variables)), a quadratic function $f(x) = x^TAx + b^Tx + c$ has $\alpha = \sigma_{\min}(2A)$ and $\beta = \sigma_{\max}(2A)$ where $\sigma_i$ is the $i$-th eigenvalue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your definition is correct?

Comment: @Redshoes Yes the definitions are correct. I double confirmed from textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, these are computationally difficult problems. For example, "merely" deciding convexity of a multivariate polynomial of degree 4 (or higher even degree) is strongly NP-hard, i.e. unless P=NP, there is no polynomial time algorithm or pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for this problem. Also deciding strict convexity and strong convexity of polynomials of even degree of four or higher is NP-hard. These results are recently proved in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1908.pdf

On the other hand, many convex functions that we encounter in practice have special structures, e.g., formed from simpler convex functions that we know their smoothness or convexity properties. Then, there is more hope to figure out specialized methods for your questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!